# setting Video Resolution using Intent

Tags: android

I'm trying to record a video in my app. What I'm trying to do is to set the video resolution to lowest resolution of the device.

I'm using this code to record a video:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

// set video quality
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 1099648L);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_FINISH_ON_COMPLETION, true);

intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
                                                        // name
// start the video capture Intent
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

is it possible? or do I need to use MediaRecorder to customize the video settings.
any thoughts will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you can use MediaRecorder to record video instead of using the ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE intent, you can set the video size in pixels.

Comment: Yes I can. But my as long as possible I want to use the ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE to use the external camera rather than to create another class for the Media Recorder. And external camera or native camera already has a lot of settings or features.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the lowest resolution might not be good approach but thats the only thing you can do, i was trying to set kinda medium resolution but failed.

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0); //sets lowest resolution
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1); //sets highest resolution
```

But the problem is samsung camera app ignore the intent extras in this case. this behaviour is same across all samsung devices. but this works fine on Google Nexus devices.
I tried on motoroa and it works fine.

For some people, as mentioned [here](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=General&messageId=251993),  `EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY` is working just opposite as it was expected to work. If we pass 1 the video quality would be worse and for 0 will be the best. **Sadly this didnt worked for me :(**

Comment: thanks for your 0 and 1 flags for EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY. that is worked.

Comment: @Salmaan is the Samsung EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY bug still persistent?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 3); // Duration in Seconds
        takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0); // Quality Low
        takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 5491520L); // 5MB
        takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.HEIGHT, 320);
        takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.WIDTH, 240);

        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, CAMERA_RQ);
        }
```